# How can I add an if clause in a [vba] custom function

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote this function

```
Function potential(Volume, Original, Better)
potential = (Original - Better) * Volume
End Function
```

Its pretty basic but what i really need is in the case when Better is blank the answer should be 0

I tried 
`potential = Application.WorksheetFunction.If(Better = 0, 0, (Original - Better) * Volume)`
result is always an error

or `potential = ((Original - Better) * Volume) * (Better / Better)` only gave an error when Better is blank

So I tried `potential = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(((Original - Better) * Volume) * (Better / Better), 0)`  with the same results

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Don't use worksheet functions for flow control. Use VBA language constructs (e.g. `If...Then...Else...End If`) for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
Function potential(ByVal Volume As Double, ByVal Original As Double, Optional ByVal Better As Double = 0) As Double
    If Better = 0 Then Exit Function
    potential = (Original - Better) * Volume
End Function
```

Comment: @ Scott Craner - Does VB/VBA default to "ByVal" when not specified as in this example?

Comment: @GlennG parameters in VBA are always `ByRef` unless specified otherwise (and yes, you want `ByVal` 99.999% of the time)